# model measurement in scikit learn

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

Working on the logistic regression, and post code sample and document. Wondering if there is any built-in API in scikit learn which calculate model measurement, like precision, recall, AUC, etc. for any model prediction results? Thanks.

Working with Python 2.7.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
=========================================================
Logistic Regression 3-class Classifier
=========================================================

Show below is a logistic-regression classifiers decision boundaries on the
`iris <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set>`_ dataset. The
datapoints are colored according to their labels.

"""
print(__doc__)


# Code source: Gaël Varoquaux
# Modified for documentation by Jaques Grobler
# License: BSD 3 clause

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model, datasets

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
Y = iris.target

h = .02  # step size in the mesh

logreg = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=1e5)

# we create an instance of Neighbours Classifier and fit the data.
logreg.fit(X, Y)

# Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
# point in the mesh [x_min, m_max]x[y_min, y_max].
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - .5, X[:, 0].max() + .5
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - .5, X[:, 1].max() + .5
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
Z = logreg.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.figure(1, figsize=(4, 3))
plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)

# Plot also the training points
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=Y, edgecolors='k', cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
plt.xlabel('Sepal length')
plt.ylabel('Sepal width')

plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

regards,
Lin

Comment: yes there is lots, take a look at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html

Comment: This is exactly what I need! I search and studied LogisticRegression related API and does not found one, and good to know there is a general implementation. :)